# HERE Tour Planning - Specifiy truck limitations

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

I understand that we can define truck limitations such as weight limit, weight per axle, height and within the truck profile (inside the problem).

However, I was not able to find any example. Here is what i tried:

```
  "profiles": [
  {
    "type": "truck",
    "name": "truck_12t",
    "options": {
      "maxGrossWeight": 12
    }
  }
]
```

It fails with the following error:

*Instance failed to match exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 5) Problem definition is not consistent with the specification.*

Does anyone got a simple example that gets me started ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to API spec there’s no option `maxGrossWeight`:
[image]

> The correct problem definition should contain only mentioned options. For example:

```
     "profiles": [
```

{

"type": "truck",

"name": "truck_12t",

"options": {

"grossWeight": 12,

"height":50

```
       }
```

}

]”